# how to make unorder list all in same block and have gap within each link (CSS)

Tags: html, css

Need a guidance from CSS pro. how can i get the expected result. Appreciated for any help.

`What i've tried so far :` [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v7xv076b/)

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply give your `<li>` elements a margin. For example:

```
ul li {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

To avoid extra spaces below the list you can remove the last margin with the `last-of-type` psuedo selector:

```
li:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

---

Assuming that you are content with the static fixed-width layout, you can also force the widths of all list items with:

```
ul li {
    width: 145px;
}
```

[Here your adjusted fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7xv076b/4/).

---

For further reference see the tutorials at [w3cschools](http://www.w3schools.com/). Specifically for the CSS [width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp) and [margin](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) properties, and the [last-of-type psuedo selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp).

Comment: Hi, thanks for a quick reply, it's working for the gap, but may i know how can to all <li> are in the same block size?